# Bamboo: create "plan branch" when pull request is created, but filter by target branch

Tags: pull-request, bamboo

[image: Create plan branch]

I want my BitBucket instance to trigger the creation of a plan branch, when a pull request is created.

But I want to filter which pull requests trigger such action: the plan branch should be created only if the pull request's *target branch* matches a particular regular expression.

The Bamboo instance is self-hosted. It is not on the Atlassian's cloud. I don't know if this makes any difference, when it comes to features.

Note: I would like to avoid setting all stage's tasks as conditional, based on the variable `repository.pr.target.Branch`. As that would make maintaining the pipelines more painful than it already is.

Also, that would result in a successful build in BitBucket for that PR. I'd like the build to not exist at all.

Having conditional stages would make maintenance easier. But Bamboo does not feature conditional stages.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not possible. I've been through the same quest and `repository.pr.target.Branch` with conditional tasks (or alternatively conditionals in shell script tasks) is the only way to go.